# Looking to measure webpages to see how far users scroll

Tags: google-tag-manager, user-experience

So, I use Google Tag Manager to track user's scroll depth.

The problem is, I want to see where most users appear to stop scrolling and leave the page. I don't know how long the page is so I can't estimate, for example, how far a 25% scroll depth is and what they see.

Is there a tool to measure webpage length so I can get a better sense of what my users are viewing? I've been looking around but most results I get are the size (mb, kb, that sort of thing) of webpages.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information with JavaScript (in GTM) and send it to Google Analytics in a custom dimension (hit level) so you can use it in the reports.